# Android marshmallow edittext OnKeyListener not fired on enter button

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

As the title says on MM devices Enter key is not recognized, the same code is working fine on 5.x. Any help here would be appreciated. Snippet of how i am using is:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/post_new_question_edittext_question"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:hint="@string/type_your_question_here"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

Here is my listerner

```
  m_editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                PostNewQuestion();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` and try.

if you want to catch done event you can use

```
(keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)
```

instead of

```
(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

Comment: If i remove "actionDone", all i get is the enter button which takes user to next line instead of invoking OnKeyListener. The real issue is OnKeyListener is not getting called. This is not working.

Comment: Dont remove and try event that i mentioned

Comment: Keycode comparison will come into picture when the event will be fired. the issue as i mentioned earlier also is event not being fired..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` from your xml and hopefully it will work.

Comment: If i remove "actionDone", all i get is the enter button which takes user to next line instead of invoking OnKeyListener. This is not working.